# Creating a Windows 10 boot drive on ubuntu (missing media driver)

Tags: drivers, usb, windows-10, iso

I have tried to do this for a week now with no success. When I boot from the usb stick it starts the installer but then I get the message about a missing media driver. So I did some research and the most likely answer is that for some dumb reason when you download the iso file it finished before being complete. I checked the hash against the table on microsoft's site and that confirms it. So now to the question. How do I download and mount the windows 10 iso when I don't have access to a windows pc?

Comment: Search "download windows 10 iso image (for offline installation)"

Comment: Hi I managed to create a working usb drive by usingmkusb

Answer (score 2):

I used mkusb to create a working usb image. I used the same download I got from microsofts website so I must have been wrong about the download being incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. mkusb-plug is my preferred tool for creating Windows installer. How did you manage to download the ISO?

Comment: I must have been wrong about the download being incomplete even though when I checked the hash against the one provided by them it was different. Still confused about that but Maybe I used the wrong number. All the ISO are available to download on microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks, it is good to hear that Microsoft has not crippled the ISO downloads.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and couldnt do it with ubuntu. An easy fix is to burn the USB with Rufus in Windows. In my case the Linux partition already installed on the pc was in MBR mode, so UEFI (GPT) USB was returning the missing drivers error.

The solution was to burn the USB in MBR mode and the installation worked perfectly. If your system is in UEFI mode try uefi settings in Rufus.

Comment: The question being how to create a Windows 10 boot drive **on Ubuntu**, saying that you can do it in Windows, also something that everybody knows, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It would have helped me a lot to know that when I faced the same problem...